# Windows 10 stuck in boot loop - startup repair not available

Tags: windows-10, boot

**Essential Summary:**
In short, I've attempted a Windows update that decided to botch itself into an infinite boot loop. I'm unable to break into startup repair regardless of how many times I powercycle during startup. After managing to boot through a brand new (installed at the time of the issue) windows installation flash drive, I tried the startup repair option, which stagnated on "attempting repairs" for 30 minutes. After I attempted to restore to a system restore point, I created before the update to be told that my machine had no restore points.

Just in case, below is an order of events, and [this is a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/rYA6tYF8) with a detailed explanation of each event, for the sake of shortening the post.

Order of events (leading up to the issue):

```
1. Microsoft store doesn't download apps with the issue of 0x80073cf9
2. Download Media Creation Tool & Download Win10 ISO from it
3. Mount ISO
4. Create System Restore Point
5. Run Setup.exe 1st time (Settings to keep all personal files)
6. Notice 1st upgrade quit(sometime after ~30%), Start 2nd upgrade(Same settings)
7. PC Restarts ~30% into 2nd upgrade,
8. Begin Restart loop
```

Description of the loop:
MSI "Press del/f11" UEFI screen for around 10 seconds -> Windows spinning dots loading circle on top of that for ~10 seconds -> Brief flash of CMD Prompt -> Brief flash of Windows screen saying roughly "undoing recent changes" -> screen blacks -> Back to start

Order of events (after issue/troubleshooting steps):

```
1. Boot into flash drive installation media
2. Greeted with Windows Setup Dialogue Box
3. Poke around in cmd line, make sure HDDs still recognized
4. Attempt Startup Repair Option - terminate after ~30 minutes
5. Attempt restore from system point
6. Informed that no restore points exist
```

Comment: This won't be too helpful but I'd recommend cloning your disk as it is at present. My parents had a similar issue with a broken upgrade and in the end I cloned their drive to a backup drive I had, put in a new disk and reinstalled windows and apps etc. What I found later on was that their original data files were in two separate locations when I got their original drive connected - the result of two failed upgrades meant that the windows.old folder got clobbered by the second upgrade attempt. Took me a couple of days to recover their data - Windows Livemail, photos etc & did lose some data.

Comment: @Enigman Not bad advise at all, I'll probably do that before I muck around too much more. However, just listing the directories on the drive I performed the upgrade on, there's no win.old folder anywhere, even among hidden folders. 
Out of curiosity, was you parent's upgrade from Win7/8, or was it an in place upgrade on Win10?

Comment: In place upgrade of Win10 - Creators update executed automatically and had much the same symptoms as you have experienced - continuous reboot loop, could not recover no matter what was tried.

Comment: Guess I'm slowly resigning to a clean install then. Needed to purge my old backup HDD anyways =P. Will probably give this post another day or so before committing to it, as I think I've exhausted all the obvious options so far.